# Date Time Format of 20131205205012.000000-000

Tags: c#

When i query using WMI the event log the time an event occurred is 20131205205012.000000-000 for example

how can i convert this to yymmdd hh:mm:ss or similar
Out of interest what format is this ?

**C# Code**

```
this.radGridViewEvents.Columns.Add("Time Written");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE EventType = 1");
        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    this.radGridViewEvents.Rows.Add(queryObj["TimeWritten"]);
}
```

Comment: So are you getting that as a string?

Comment: (It looks like it's yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff with probably a UTC offset at the end.)

Comment: I added the c# code to get the data

Comment: That doesn't tell us what type the value is. I suspect it's a string, but I suggest you debug and see what the type is - the indexer just returns `object`, so that doesn't tell us much.

Comment: You could try and feed it through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime.aspx) converter and see if it converts to a DateTime

Comment: And does the value ever end with anything other than "-000"?

Comment: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.07.scriptingguy.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet no it always ends in -000 which to your point means GMT which is correct. FFFFFF is alot of the time 000000 which is strange seeing as it is supposed to be fractions of a second (that a log is written)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its UTC format, similar to this but without the seperators/punctuation;

```
2013-12-05T18:13:27+00:00
```

I am unsure what the -000 represents, but I assume the rest are the second fractions. One way to parse it is to use DateTime.ParseExact. Assuming you trim off the -000, you can parse the rest like so;

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("20131205205012.000000", 
                                           "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                           DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                           DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Answer (score 0):

-000 is the GMT offset, it can be positive also